# PHP used in HTML elements, to determine odd/even, code ignores background image

Tags: php, css

I created a page to display messages that are saved into a database.The messages are displayed with a picture. I have the following DIV layout:

```
<div id="MessageWrapper">

    <div id="MessagePicture"></div>

    <div id="MessageText">

        <div id="MessageTitle"></div>

        <div id="MessageContent"></div>

    </div>

</div>
```

I wanted the div 'MessagePicture' and 'MessageText' to alternate their position (left and right) So The final code I have is:

```
$i = 0;
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result)) 
{
$class = (++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';

echo '

    <div id="MessageWrapper">

    <div id="MessagePicture" class="'.$class.'">

        <style>

        #MessagePicture { 
            background-image: url(../../../Images/'.stripslashes($Row['Code']).'.png);  
            background-repeat: no-repeat; 
            background-position: center

        </style>

            </div>

            <div id="MessageText" class="'.$class.'">

                <div id="MessageTitle">

                 <h1>'.$Row['NameBox'].'</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="MessageContent">

            <p>'.nl2br($Row['MessageBox']).'</p>
        </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

The problem I'm facing: although the parsed source code has different codes ($Row['Code']) in the url of the background image, all the messages display the same image.
It is always the first image of the first ($Row['Code']) that is entered into the database.

Does anyone know how to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same id.

Comment: How should I arrange my code to make it work?

Comment: You should use some inline styles in this case

Comment: Also, you can use `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)` selectors in css instead of `$class = (++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';`. [More information about these selectors avalible here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Comment: you forgot the closing `}` of the `while` loop

Comment: Of less relevance, just as an FYI, you should note that `(++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';` is incorrect. `1%2 = 1` (true) and `2%2 = 0` (false), which means that you are saying 1 is "even" and 2 is "odd".

Answer (score 0):

Give each of your divs a unique id.  For example:

```
$i = 0;
while ($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($Result)) 
{
    $class = (++$i % 2) ? 'even' : 'odd';
    echo '
<div id="MessageWrapper'.$i.'">
<div id="MessagePicture'.$i.'" class="'.$class.'">
    <style>
        #MessagePicture'.$i.' { 
            background-image: url(../../../Images/'.stripslashes($Row['Code']).'.png);  
        }
    </style>
... etc ...
}
```

You end up with the first `div` having an `id` of `MessagePicture1` and a corresponding `#MessagePicture1` style, the next one `MessagePicture2`, and so on.